# Problems with Auto-layout and uitableview

Tags: uitableview, constraints, autolayout

I have a view on the top of my screen.
My view has a variable height, so i use a height constraint on it and it works.

I want to place a uitableview on the bottom of my variable view; I used vertical spacing between my view and my tableview, but the tableview doesn't move, it keeps the position of the storyboard.

Is there a particular thing to do with auto layout and an uitableview? What's the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I understand you have a UIView added to your storyboard's scene and you have a UITableView inside it, the UIView has a variable height, so what constraints did you use on the UIView? but anyway there's nothing special about a UITableView constraints in your situation, you could do the following

1. UITableView Leading space -> UIView
2. UITableView Trailing space -> UIView
3. UItableView Bottom space -> UIView
4. UItableView Fixed height

This is based on what I understood, if you submit your project's code, I might be able to fix it for you and explain more.